# roots of polynomials and perfect square

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

If $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial with integer coefficients, and all roots of $f(x) = 0$ are distinct. How to prove that there exist infinitely many positive integer $n$ such that $f(n)$ is not a perfect square?

Thank you

Comment: Note that all roots of $f$ are distinct, then $$\gcd(f,\frac{df}{dx})=1$$(Note that all constants are units in the ring of polynomials).

Answer (score 4):

I know how to prove it using some deep mathematics.

Let $C$ be the algebraic variety defined (over $\mathbb Q$) by the equation $y^2 = f(x)$.

Under the assumption that $f$ have different roots (in fact, a weaker assumption that $f$ is not a square of another polynomial will suffice), we know that $C$ defines a curve (i.e. it is irreducible). It is birationally equivalent to a unique projective smooth curve $C'$, which has genus $g = \lfloor \frac{d - 1}2\rfloor$, where $d$ is the degree of $f$.

Now we may apply [Siegel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points): if $g > 0$, then there are only finitely many integral points on $C$, hence not all $f(n)$ can be squares.

The case $g = 0$ is an easy exercise.

---

This could be an overkill, but that's what I first thought about.