# Can polynomials which are not $\ell$th powers "often" assume $\ell$th powers as values?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

If a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has the property that $p(n)$ is a perfect square for every integer $n$, then $p(x)=g(x)^2$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. This is well-known. For instance, see [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5eb7/4363199754164fdf7bbc77925a98c1eb435b.pdf) paper. This doesn't just hold for squares; indeed, it holds for all $\ell$th powers.

I'm wondering if we can get stronger results in terms of considering the *asymptotic density*. For instance, is the following true?

> For any $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$, put $$P_{\ell}(p) := \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{\#\{k \in [N] : f(k) = j^{\ell} \ \text{for some}  \ j \in \mathbb{Z}\}}{N}$$
>   Then $P_{\ell}(p) > 0$ if and only if $p=g^{\ell}$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  (Note we may regard $P_{\ell}(p)$ as being undefined if the limit does not exist).

Comment: Your question is answered in the paper that you linked.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: Where?  I don't see anything of this sort in it.

Comment: @EricWofsey Theorem 1. Of course, a much stronger, and useful, result than this question. Instead of a density testing the evaluation at who knows what values, it tests the values for $|x_i|<C$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: Theorem 1 does not answer this question.  The asymptotic density of $\ell$th powers could be positive without having an $\ell$th power for all sufficiently small $x$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod MathematicsStudent1122 is not asking for an algorithm, but for a theorem. Also, just outright saying "this question is garbage" just comes out as rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to have answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437507/roots-of-polynomials-and-perfect-square/3437529#3437529). I think the same proof should work here, at least for the case $\ell = 2$.

For general $\ell$ it probably also works, because you should still get a curve. There are nevertheless some details to check.